# Why does CreateFile take forever?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I have a thread in my program which tries to `CreateFile` in order to lock a usb device, however, sometimes instead of failing, it takes forever. Has anyone else encountered this problem? Is there any way I can set a timeout for this function? The code is something like this:

```
string file = @"\\.\" + DriveLetter[0] + ":";
handle = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, 0x3, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing a native call?

Comment: I need to lock the device temporarily using `DeviceIoControl`. Do you have any better suggestions?

Comment: Why not switch to C++? If you are going close to the HW...

Comment: Can we assume there's a typo?  You appear to be setting `file` to the drive letter, then doing `CreateFile` passing it `filename`.

Comment: By "forever," do you mean that it hangs and never returns, or that it takes a really long time?

Comment: A really long time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The taking forever seemed to have been some sort of conflict with the main form thread.

Eventually, I moved the locking functions containing the `CreateFile` operation to a separate thread where it wouldn't compete with the UI thread and it works fine now.

Comment: Perhaps Windows is sending a message to applications (including your application) warning them that the device is about to be removed, and can't return from the CreateFile until they respond.

Comment: Yeah, it's ugly to peep into the computer's brain, we're always better of guessing :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to lock it to make it inaccessible -as a device- or to "block" detaching it (as e.g. it's a pen)?
EDIT: sorry I'm not allowed to add comment :S
Anyways. If the locking is important you can do that easily with devcon: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272
, and a sample code:
http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/dotnet/337951/337951/programatically-enable--disable-usb-port-using-cnet/ 
in case you don't want to use the exe with params all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, was already considering this alternative. Will look into it.